# Network Interface not enabling when provisioning VM from Ansible

Tags: networking, module, ansible, vmware

I'm provisioning VM from ansible-playbook using VMware template, I can see the VM is created successfully but the network interface is not enabled automatically. I have to manually go to the VMware console and then edit the settings of the VM to enable the Network Interface. Kindly check the below playbook tasks and suggest what correction I need to do to enable the Network Interface when running the playbook

```
tasks:
- name: Create VM from template
  vmware_guest:
    validate_certs: False
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    esxi_hostname: "{{ esxhost }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    name: "{{ name }}"
    folder: TEST
    template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
    disk:
      - size_gb: "{{ disk_size | default(32) }}"
        type: thin
        datastore: "{{ datastore }}"
    networks:
    - name: VM Network
      ip: 172.17.254.223
      netmask: 255.255.255.0
      gateway: 172.17.254.1
      device_type: vmxnet3
      state: present
    wait_for_ip_address: True
    hardware:
      memory_mb: "{{ vm_memory | default(2000) }}"
    state: present
  register: newvm

- name:  Changing network adapter
  vmware_guest_network:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
    name: "{{ name }}"
    validate_certs: no
    networks:
    - name: "VM Network"
      device_type: vmxnet3
      state: present
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html#ansible-collections-community-vmware-vmware-guest-module) you can "connect" the network interface via `connected: true`. There is also a parameter `start_connected`. So add both to your networks dictionary

```
networks:
  - name: VM Network
    ip: 172.17.254.223
    netmask: 255.255.255.0
    gateway: 172.17.254.1
    device_type: vmxnet3
    connected: true
    start_connected: true
```

I can't see a default value in the documentation, but I assume - they are per default false.

Also - there is no `state` parameter in networks dict list.

Comment: In the template there is no NIC, when I launch a VM then only I create a network interface, also I have enabled the above mentioned connected and start_connected but still same issue. Interface is not coming up, have to manually goto vcenter and enable by clicking the checkbox against the Network Interface

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/45834

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before. This happen because you're using VDS and on the vm-template side the `open-vm-tools` is installed instead of `vmware-tools`.
I was able to fix this issue by applying this workaround:

- First install `vmware-tools` in the template instead of `open-vm-tools`.
- Make sure in the playbook that the VM got those parameters:

  ```
  connected: true /
  start_connected: true
  ```
- In case there is a need for `open-vm-tools` after, you can simply run a small playbook which uninstall `vmware-tools` and reinstall the `open-vmtools` instead.